# Remove duplicates from a Circular Linked List in O(n) time and O(1) space

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Suppose there is a **Circular** singly linked list with n nodes. Given a pointer to the head, how to remove the nodes which contain duplicate data in O(n) time and O(1) space? The interviewer asks specifically not to use a hash table and work only with pointers.

Comment: Do you mean when adding them or when you have a ready made list? I don't think you can in the latter case. Or did I spoil the answer here?

Comment: Short answer: you cant.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without additional constraints (e.g. that the list is sorted, or the element values are bounded). It wouldn't even be possible in an array, let a lone a linked list.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes when I have a ready made list.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I sorted the linked List by merge sort and removed duplicates in O(n logn) time and O(1) space.

Comment: That's pretty good, but it's not O(n) :)

Comment: Nor is merge sort O(1) space -- it's O(log n) space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastet possible way to remove duplicates from a circular linked list is in O(n log(n)). This is by sorting them and then removing duplicates using the following algorithm. We know that any duplicates are now next to each other, which is why we remove as we traverse, so we only move n times.

```
removeDuplicatesOf(node, head)
    if(node == node.next || node.next == head)
        return
    else if(node.value == node.next.value)
        node.next = node.next.next
        removeDuplicatesOf(node, head)
    else
        removeDuplicatesOf(node.next, head)
```

This runs in O(n) for worst case, removing all duplicates in a sorted list. Since the two arguments are singulare the space complexity is O(1). The problem here though is that you need the data sorted.

Since you are only allowed to work with pointers, imagine node to be a pointer itself, node.next, is the pointer to the next node. node.value is the stored value at the node location. I like the object notation better since it is better readable.

All other methods will result in equal or higher time complexity. The problem with the proposed idea is that there is no way of comparing data, without looking back at it. This additional step makes it impossible to be of a complexity below O(n log(n)). The only exception is if your list is presorted.

If this is a question in an interview then it is likely that one of two options apply:

1) The employer needs a new interviewer who understands time complexity better.

2) This is a trick question to test your understanding of time complexity. In this case the answer would be it is impossible.

Latter is far more likely.